# How to replace all instances of <p><br></p> with an empty string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

i want to grab some html content and store in a variable. Then i want to clean that content by replacing all instances of `<p><br></p>` with empty string

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```js
$('p').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text()); 
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Testing
</div>
<p>Test 1</p>
<p>Test 2</p>
```

For grab an `HTML` element, please use element `tag`, `classname` or `id`, here I've used element tag.

Instead of storing into a variable, I've done `console.log`.

For cleaning the content with empty string, you can use `empty` method in `JavaScript` like `$(this).empty`, but it will clear the content not element. So, I've used `remove` method to remove the element.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your response. The biggest challenge is that the content can be mixed up. Sometimes the data can be something like "<p>Hi guys <p><br/></p></p>"

Comment: i'm using summernote WYSIWYG editor, which allows for html and text to be saved to the database, but i need to remove the <p><br/></p> instances which can possibly be nested in other tags such as p tags

Comment: @JulianTabona Whatever code I've provided will work in all condition. Still if you are facing issue, please create a jsfiddle, will help you out.